# Close button closes active tab in tabpanel instead of tab button is attached to (tab dynamically created) EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. I have site I'm working with that uses EXTjs and the tabpanel functionality. I'm creating the tab in the following form.

```
tabWrapper = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'fit',
    tools: tools,
    id: tabConfig.itemId+'-wrapper',
    title: tabConfig.title,
    hidden: tabConfig.hidden,
    hideMode: 'offsets',
    closable: tabConfig.closable,
```

Please notice the closable tag. When set to enable/true it creates an x button to close the tab. This button however is closing whatever tab is active instead of the tab it is attached to. Is this a known glitch or is there something in my code that does this?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because of non-unique ids. Using ids in Ext is a *very bad* practice that almost always leads to problems. Remove id config option (not only from this tab) and try again.

Also, do not overnest - you do not need to wrap a component in a panel for adding it to tab panel.